# jQuery: Get next page via ajax and append it with animation

Tags: ajax, jquery

I am getting next page on my wordpress blog using jquery, finding the desired div and appending it to the existing one. This part works without a problem. But, what I need to do is, to add slideDown animation to it.
This is how my working code so far looks like:

```
$.get(next_page, function(data) {
    var response = $(data);
    var more_div = $(response).find('.FeaturedRow1').html();
    $('.FeaturedRow1').append(more_div).slideDown('slow');
    $('.navigation').not(':last').hide();
```

I tried adding hide() to response, more_div as well as append lines. In the first case, I get error stating that it cannot set property display of undefined. 
In the second case, in the console it display HTML and says "has no method hide". I also tried adding a line $(more_div).hide() but again, I get the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'display' of undefined".
If I use hide in the 3rd line

```
$('.FeaturedRow1').hide().append(more_div).slideDown('slow');
```

it hides the whole FeaturedRow1 div and animates it, that takes me to the top of the div, which is what I don't want.

EDIT: Here's the important HTML structure and jQuery code for the desired section

```
<div class="FeaturedRow1">
  <div class="postspage">
    //list of posts here
  </div>
  <div class="navigation">
    <span class="loadless">
      //hyperlink to previous page
    </span>
    <span class="loadmore">
      //hyperlink to next page
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

When you click on the hyperlink inside the loadmore, the following jQuery code gets called

```
$('.loadmore a').live('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var next_page = $(this).attr('href');
    $.get(next_page, function(data) {
        var $response = $(data);
        var $more_div = $response.find('.FeaturedRow1').hide();
        $more_div.appendTo('.FeaturedRow1').delay(100).slideDown('slow')
        $('.navigation').not(':last').hide();
    });
});
$('.loadless').live('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($('.postpage').length != 1) {
        $('.postpage').last().remove();
    } 
    $('.navigation').last().remove();
    $('.navigation').last().show();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get error as you are using `html` method which returns a string not a jQuery object, try the following.

```
var $response = $(data);
var $more_div = $response.find('.FeaturedRow1').hide();
$more_div.appendTo('.FeaturedRow1').delay(100).slideDown('slow');
//$('.navigation').not(':last').hide();
```

Update:

```
$.get(next_page, function(data) {
    var $response = $(data);
    var more_div = $response.find('.FeaturedRow1').html();
    $('<div/>').hide()
               .append(more_div)
               .appendTo('.FeaturedRow1')
               .delay(100)
               .slideDown('slow')
    $('.navigation').not(':last').hide();
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work. But, there's a small typo in your reply, the appendTo line should have been

    $(more_div).appendTo('.FeaturedRow1').slideDown('slow');

But, one problem I am seeing after this change is, that the div is loading multiple times for some weird reason.

Comment: @mehulved `$more_div` is a jQuery object and you can call `appendTo`, do you mean it doesn't work without wrapping it in jQuery wrapper?

Comment: I was defining it is var more_div instead of var $more_div as you've done. After changing it as per your example, it works.
But, this new problem of multiple divs loading is creating a problem.

Comment: @mehulved `.find('.FeaturedRow1')` selects all the element from other page with class of `featuredRow1`, if you want to load only one element you can use first method.`$response.find('.FeaturedRow1').first().hide();`

Comment: what it is doing is, it gets 2nd page correctly, when it comes to 3rd page, it gets it twice, for the 4th page, it gets the page 4 times, including moving the 2nd instance of the 3rd page after the 2nd instance of 4th page and keeps getting higher number of pages as I go higher.

Comment: @mehulved The problem should be related to how you are requesting page, see the network tab and check how many ajax requesting is executed.

Comment: that doesn't work. I will add the structure of my HTML code to help you understand the new problem. There is only one .FeaturedRow1, containing .postpage as well as .navigation which are both needed.

Comment: I am very sure I am pressing the button once, and I tried it various times on various pages, with the exact same result.

Comment: @mehulved Okay, please post your event handler.

Comment: Double checked in the Network tab in Chrome inspector, only one request is being sent.

Comment: @mehulved The issue is you have more than one `.FeaturedRow1` element after ajax calls, you can use `first` selector `$more_div.appendTo('.FeaturedRow1:first')`

Comment: How can I avoid creating multiple instances of FeaturedRow1? With my earlier code I was extracting just the html because I can keep removing the postpage only.

Comment: Your solution does indeed work. But, it would be great if I can have only one FeaturedRow1, in case I have to do more with it in the future, having multiple of the divs will create problem.
Should I instead move the navigation div inside postpage to have just one FeaturedRow1?

Comment: @mehulved You can create another element and append it instead, see the updated code.